# Problem of bodies in motion in circles.

Tags: geometry, circles, problem-solving

Consider two circles of radii $4\;cm$ and $8\;cm$, respectively, both circles have the same center $C$ and is two bodies $A$ and $B$, so that $A$ is smaller circumference of the trajectory at a constant speed of $5\; km/h$, while $B$ is also the greatest circumference at a constant speed of $10\;km/h$.

Knowing that the bodies initially form an angle of $90^o$ with respect to the center $C$, where the time needed and how to calculate so that the points $A$, $B$ and $C$ are aligned?

And how to calculate the next time they met aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular velocity of bodies A and B are :
$$\omega_A=\frac{v_A}{r_A}=\frac{5km/h}{4cm}=\frac{1250}{36}rad/sec$$
$$\omega_B=\frac{v_B}{r_B}=\frac{10km/h}{8cm}=\frac{1250}{36}rad/sec$$

Since both bodies have same angular speed, the angle between two bodies (with respect to the center C) does not change with time, and considering the fact that at the initial time this angle is $90^0$, the points A, B and C can not be aligned in any time.

Proof:

$$\theta_A(t)=\omega_A t$$
$$\theta_B(t)=\omega_B t\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$$

(In the latter equation, choose $\frac{\pi}{2}$ if at $t=0$, $\theta_B$ is larger than $\theta_A$, or choose $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ if at $t=0$, $\theta_A$ is larger than $\theta_B$) Therefore,

$$\theta_B(t)-\theta_A(t)=(\omega_B -\omega_A)t\pm\frac{\pi}{2}=\pm\frac{\pi}{2} \neq 0, \pm \pi, \pm 2\pi , ...$$

Comment: Wow, very nice ... 

Now, what if it was unlike speeds. 

If the speed of Body $B$ were $10km/h$ and the body was $5km / h$?

Comment: If the angular speeds are different, first find the angular speeds in the same way, then using the last equation $\theta_B(t)-\theta_A(t)=...=0,\pm \pi,...$ you can find all positive times which two bodies aligned.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Transform the linear speed into angular speed.

What is the angle between $A$ and $B$ respect to the center $C$ at any given time?

Comment: So I have to create a function that gives me the angle between $A$ and $B$ with respect to the center $C$, and observe the roots of this function, right? 

It is a grand idea. 

How could I create this function? Transform this speed angular velocity?

Comment: To transform the linear velocity to angular one, look at how much time $A$ or $B$ take to complete a full circle. That's also the time to do a $360^\circ$ angle. Once you have the angular velocity of $A$ and $B$, substract it and add $90^\circ$ and you'll have a function that tells you the angle between $A$ and $B$ at any given time.
I suggest you don't substitute $\pi$ for a numerical aproximation or use decimal expressions. Use fractions. This way the (surprising) answer will be more clear.

Comment: Ah yes, this method is very interesting. 

Just an observation, correct me if I'm wrong.$$\omega_A=\frac{v_A}{r_A}=\frac{5km/h}{4cm}=\frac{500.000cm/3.600s}{4cm}=\frac{5.000}{4\cdot36}=\frac{1.250}{36}$$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Yes, note that it's in radians/second and not degrees/second. So when you compute the angle between $A$ and $B$ over time, you must add $\pi/2$ radians instead of $90^\circ$. You'll find that the angle between $A$ and $B$ is constant and therefore will never be aligned with $C$.